# Laravel custom artisan command act as authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel

I have created my custom `artisan command` that do a certain job and this job ask for the user permission (user should be authenticated as ADMIN to do this job)

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $invoice_type = $this->argument('invoice_type');
        // ACTION HERE THAT NEED USER AUTHENTICATION
        $this->info('done..');
    }
```

## Question is:

Is there a way so I could make this command act as certain user?

Command signature: `protected $signature = 'invoices:net_total {invoice_type}';`

Comment: There is `Auth::loginUsingId($id);` but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for. You can probably prompt the user for their username and password and authenticate it the same way as you would for the web.

Comment: @aynber lol it solved it! thanks :D

Comment: check if the current user has the admin role, and if he has, make executing...